# use subprocess.run with check = True where the command is expected to return a non-zero exit code

Tags: python, subprocess, pylint

When using `subprocess.run` it's recommended to use `check = True` (https://pycodequ.al/docs/pylint-messages/w1510-subprocess-run-check.html). However, there might be a subprocess I want to run where a non-zero exit code is expected, and I'm wondering whether there's an approach which will satisfy both pylint and my code.

For example:

```py
subprocess.run('ls | grep sdfjosidjf', shell = True, check = True)
```

Will (most likely) raise:

```
CalledProcessError: Command 'ls | grep sdfjosidjf' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

What if this is exactly what I'm expecting or even wanting though?

I could remove `check = True` and just disable pylint for this line, I'm wondering if there's a more general approach than `check = True` though, perhaps I'm expecting either `0` or `1` as exit codes.

Comment: You could add `|| true` to the end of the command so it always returns a zero status. But I would just disable the lint check.

Comment: The message says "without explicitly set `check`" not with check=True so setting check=False, as the answer below says, is what you want

Comment: In this particular case, reimplementing all of your code in pure Python is a vastly superior solution. `files = [file for file in os.listdir() if 'sdfjosidjf' in file]`

Comment: @tripleee it was just an example used to generate the referenced CalledProcessError.

Comment: It generalizes to a number of situations; at the very least, you can replace the `grep` and run just a single subprocess without `shell=True` and gain more control over the subprocess as well as reduce its resource consumption.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just set `check=False`?

```
subprocess.run('ls | grep sdfjosidjf', shell=True, check=False)
```